# solar2d (corona) not building android apk on linux android-template.zip doesn't exist

Tags: linux, build, apk, solar2d, corona

starting with a new solar2d install built from source on linux, create an empty project, make no changes, it builds and runs on linux, but does not build the android apk, errors out like this:

```
BUILD FAILED
/home/user/corona/bin/Resources/build.xml:98: src '/home/user/android/resource/android-template.zip' doesn't exist.

Total time: 0 seconds
```

what do I have to do to build an apk on linux with solar2d (built from source) ?

specifically I tried this - install dependencies:

```
sudo apt install libalut-dev libfreetype-dev libsdl2-dev
```

(cmake, build-essential, git, vi etc already present)

```
git clone --recursive https://github.com/coronalabs/corona.git
```

cd into the corona/bin directory and build:

```
cmake ..
make
```

after the build is complete, from within the bin directory, start solar2d:

```
./Solar2D
```

new project, blank template, give it a name, ok

in the blank project window, File->Build->Android, click Build

the above error appears. According to the doc, the android sdk is not required, but I installed it, and then installed android studio as well, and also openjdk-8-jdk and openjdk-17-jdk and openjdk-20-jdk, same result. I tried these specific steps on two real machines and a virtual machine, same result, it is reproducible. I also tried to build the apk for the Balloontap example (that is, not an empty app), same error.

The file it complains about, android-template.zip is not anywhere in the system, I suspect it is either generated, or it has to be downloaded from somewhere else. And maybe some environment variable has to be set, or there must be a configuration file with directives, but if so, I could not find the doc for how to do that.

So my question is this - what do I have to do to build the apk with solar2d (built from source - not installed via snap) on linux?
(I haven't tried with the snap version, and don't want to install snap)